# JAXB equivalent of the JPA @Embdedded annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, java-ee-6, jaxb2

have a quick question:

I have the following two classes.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "address")
  private Address address;

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

  @XmlElement(name = "post_code")
  private String postCode;

  @XmlElement(name = "country")
  private String country;
}
```

This produces the following JSON:

```
{ 
  "name" : "john",
  "address" : {
      "post_code" : "XYZ 123",
      "country" : "US"
  }
}
```

But I actually want something more like this (so its similar in nature to the @Embedded in JPA):

```
{ 
  "name" : "john",
  "post_code" : "XYZ 123",
  "country" : "US"
}
```

So the embedded object fields are 'pulled up'. I noticed on stackoverflow, it was mentioned that you can use MOXy's @XmlPath(".") to do this. But is there no way from the standard java EE spec to do this and not a MOXy specific annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a standard [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) annotation to accomplish what can be done with [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlPath(".")` annotation as of JAXB 2.2.

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for the response, you have any idea if something like this is in the pipeline for the standard?

Comment: @MiloJasper - This functionality currently isn't planned.  You can enter a spec enhancement for using the `spec` component in the JAXB JIRA:  https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Acomponents-panel